# Linq Select wont retrieve beyond 3 sub levels of object data in EF Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I have replaced object names with fictional ones, before anyone questions the oddness of my business case for this db :)

If I replace FavouriteBook.Name in the code below with FavouriteBookId.ToString() I will get this back fine, as there is always a favourite book if there is a user.
The following code also works if a shop has no users. But once there are users.. It doesn’t seem to want to get to the data if it goes any levels deeper than Profile.

(Profile is a mandatory object of user, and favourite book is a mandatory object of Profile. "Name" is a string property on the FavouriteBook object)

```
var ret = _context.Shops.Where(x => x.ShopId == shopId);
var selected= ret.Select(y => new UserSummaryRow //my DTO
{
    //…other properties being set have been trimmed
    UserFavouriteBook = 
      y.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == y.UserId) == null ? "N/A" 
    : y.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == y.UserId).Profile.FavouriteBook.Name

});
var summary = await selected.ToListAsync();
return summary;
```

When the line with the "await" on executes, the api method that called this repository method returns bad request with the error:

> - $exception  {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] ) 
>     at
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.TaskLiftingExpressionVisitor.*ExecuteAsync[T](IReadOnlyList`1
>     taskFactories, Func`2 selector)    at
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.AsyncSelectEnumerable`2.AsyncSelectEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken
>     cancellationToken)    at
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken
>     cancellationToken)    at
>     System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate*[TSource,TAccumulate,TResult](IAsyncEnumerable`1
>     source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 accumulator, Func`2 resultSelector,
>     CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at {namespace of repo
>     method}(Int32 RecId, List`1 statuses) in .cs:line
>     2104    at {namespace on api controller method}(String dtoString) in
>     C:\Dev}path to repo}:line 608}   System.NullReferenceException

Output shows:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Error: An exception occurred in
>   the database while iterating the results of a query for context type
>   '{namespace of my context}'.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.TaskLiftingExpressionVisitor._ExecuteAsync[T](IReadOnlyList`1
>   taskFactories, Func`2 selector)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.AsyncSelectEnumerable`2.AsyncSelectEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)

I'm using .NET Core / EF core / SQL server 13.0.

Comment: I do not understand this part:  x => x.User == y.UserId. should it not be like that? x => x.UserId == y.UserId

Comment: @Y.Y. yes sorry I've updated it now

Comment: Take a look at the Include and IncludeThen methods. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-2.1

Comment: @ArjayH. Include is not applicable when using selects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can' say exactly what the problem is, because it depends on EF Core version used - EF Core query translation / processing is still unstable. It would have been nice if you have included the EF Core logging output like executed SQL query(es), client evaluation warnings if any etc.

But in general expressions like this

```
y.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == y.UserId).Profile.FavouriteBook.Name
```

are always suspicious - the correct execution depends purely on the query provider implementation of properties of a potentially `null` "object" returned by `FirstOrDefault`. LINQ to Objects definitely will throw NRE. EF Core if uses server evaluation should be able to handle it by returning `null`, but according to the exception it doesn't due to either translating or  client/mixed result evaluation.

With that being said, what I personally would try is to use the equivalent "natural" way of returning `null` final value by using `Where` + `Select` containing the final property and *then* applying `FirstOrDefault`, e.g.

```
UserFavouriteBook = y.User
    .Where(x => x.UserId == y.UserId)
    .Select(x => x.Profile.FavouriteBook.Name)
    .FirstOrDefault() ?? "N/A"
```

Comment: thanks, that worked! The SQL it builds puts in a sub select top 1 statement, rather than a join but I'm happy enough. It just makes no sense to me with the other way, why it can get properties of Profile, which is within user, but it cant get properties of favourite book which is within Profile.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your referenced entities are not loaded on demand. Do you have Lazy loading defined properly?

You can load these references directly by calling

> .Include()

So you need to change

```
_context.Shops.Include(s=> s.User.Profile.FavouriteBook)
```

Then you can do rest of filtering and projecting.

Comment: Include is not applicable when using selects